# Centering several buttons WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, ide

I was writing C# code in winforms. In winForms using this menu (in the picture) I make center several buttons. But I can not find out any way to make center some elements horizontally in WPF.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HorizontalAlignment property. For example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Width="50" Margin="5"></Button>
    <Button Width="50" Margin="5"></Button>
    <Button Width="50" Margin="5"></Button>
    <Button Width="50" Margin="5"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```